I can't seem to be able to password protect shared folders on a LAN using a crossover cable
2 PCs both on Win 10 Pro build 19045.3448, using a crossover cable.  What's a good method that allows me to share folders bidirectionally, but still protects the folders so unauthorized access is difficult?
I can share folders no problem as long as I select "Everyone".  But ideally what I want to do is to allow bidirectional access only to the 2 computers; one PC is usually connected to the internet via Wifi, the other is a music DAW for live gigs and never goes online, and I want to ensure that it stays protected.  I definitely can't encrypt the files/folders, since I run complex music software that needs access to the files.
I tried setting up users for sharing.  However when I go to Permissions for the folder, check 'Users" as the object, and try to add a user, I get "user cannot be found".  Currently both computers "see" each other.  Maybe I should be using a workgroup?

first, share permissions stack on top of file system permissions, so you need both permissions to access the share, and permissions to access the directory that is being shared. Microsoft recommends setting share permissions to "Everyone | Full Control" and then letting the actual disk permissions control the access. this is because disk permissions actually live on the disk, but share permissions are stored in the registery, making them impossible to backup and restore, except when restoring the full OS (not building the new OS and importing the data). Second is this a domain or a workgroup?

You need to explicitly share the file with the user on the respective machine, even if they have the same name, they are different users and don’t exist on the respective machine
